# How to disable the title on the ActionBar in Main Launcher Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I checked this issue, couldn't find an answer.
there are 3 places I checked that show the label on 3 separated places in my android phone or app.

1. Under the logo of the app
2. In the app processes which show's the active apps, (from that window you can close the app process)
3. In the most annoying place, the "splash" action bar title (It happens before the MAIN activity UI start, when it loading the activity `onCreate` I believe), which most of us want to get rid of usually.

The 3 places are:

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" <!-- 1--- the first place-->
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".LoadingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" <!-- 2--- the second place-->
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name"> <!-- 3--- the third place-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I checked on my phone (LG4 - android 5.1).

I saw that place 2 print on the action bar and the process but place 3 print on under the app icon in the phone.

BUT! when I checked in another phone (Hawaii P9 - android 6.0)

I saw place 2 printed under the app icon in the phone, unlike in LG4 which was place 3 who did this.

---

The main reason I actually checked it, is that I don't want the title to appear in the action bar, while I want it to appear under the app icon and in the processes.

Any help from an expert?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for commenting in the answer section but that's cuz of the low reputation, will you add your onCreate method code in order to tell you how to use

```
.setTitle(" ");
```

in which you set the title blank to make the app name doesn't appear if that helps you

Answer (score 1):

1) You could override the action bar , to use your custom action bar layout.

```
getSupportActionBar.setCustomView("your custom view");
```

2) If you just want to hide the title , you could set the title using

```
getSupportActionBar.setTitle("");
getSupportActionBar.setSubtitle("");
```

Comment: @LamaTo can you please mark this as correct answer if this helped you ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
}
```

Comment: It's better to include some explanation/context around your code rather than just having a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answers you gave me, I figure a way to do what I need in a way.

I changed the main launcher activity to extend from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`, that way I could use your suggerstions you listed.
(Although I still wonder how to do it with the regular Activity)

The style themes was also enough for me, and it worked in a neater way!

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

This xml style, fix the selected PrimaryColor in all of the wanted places and won't show the title in the main launch activity loading actionbar, while showing it under the icon and in the processes!